# Website will not center

Tags: css, wordpress

Working with a Wordpress theme, and needed to have the blue blur background stay with the slider when the browser window is re-sized. I have achieved that goal, but I have noticed that when you narrow the browser, everything does not stay centered there is a large space on the left. What would be the best way to remedy this?

http://www.stringcreative.ca/wp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sites a bit of a mess, you need to have the wrappers with the image, then the containers the same size centered

```
#wrapper {
background: #000b1a url("http://www.stringcreative.ca/wp/wp-content/themes/Rbox2Pro/images/masthead.jpg") no-repeat fixed top center;
}

#header_container {
margin: 0 auto;
height: 117px;
width: 960px;
position: relative;
}
```

dont need a lot of the position's set to absolute, and margins at - to get it to fit.
also look into the 960 Grid System. i use it all the time, and saves me loads of time getting the site to fit. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's because your solution for centered the slider is inelegant, and relies on fixed widths and absolute positioning to make it look right.

To fix it, you need to change a few things.

Change **#homebgw** to:

```
#homebgw {
    background: url("http://www.stringcreative.ca/wp/wp-content/themes/Rbox2Pro/images/masthead.jpg") no-repeat scroll 50% -117px transparent;
    height: 411px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Change **#header** to:

```
#header {
    background: url("http://www.stringcreative.ca/wp/wp-content/themes/Rbox2Pro/images/masthead.jpg") no-repeat scroll 50% 0;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    width: 1400px;
}
```

Quite simply, you don't need absolute positioning to solve the issues you posted above.  If you're using absolute positioning and negative margins to correct center alignment issues, you're probably doing something wrong.  Keep it simple, and Google how to achieve the results you desire.  The net is full of helpful documentation to achieve these basic results without hacking up your code with fixes ;)